# Laravel Admin Panel - Password Reset

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

Ok so I just had a laravel admin panel installed and when I accessed I changed my password and logged out. Now my neither my new or old password work I tried everything and nothing seems to let me back in.

I accessed phpmyadmin to try and reset it through there and tried updating my password using md5 & sh1 but still password wont work. Have no idea what other things I can try.

In phpmyadmin in type it says varchar(191) and I can choose any function to generate the password but don't know if laravel only accepts certain types of functions or am I just doing it wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash` to generate your password hash like this:

```
$new_password = Hash::make('your textplain password');
```

Comment: Hi Professor, sorry for asking but I'm fairly new to all this... Is this a location inside my cpanel where I create the file?

Can you go in to a little bit more detail. Thanks!

Comment: No, it's not a route. I'm talking about your application code. You should take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/hashing. Laravel uses Bcrypt to hash your passwords.

Comment: Ok got it. Will give it a read and see if I can figure it out.